# How to remove escapes from zsh history

Tags: zsh

If I use escaped EOLs in a command and view the history, the command includes escape characters which can't simply be copy/pasted.

eg

```
ls \
/etc
```

Shows in history like:

```
ls \\n/etc
```

Which I can't easily copy/paste/edit to a different terminal. Is there an option or other method to make the history result copy/pasteable?

Compared with bash which obliterates the `\\n` and shows `ls /etc`.

(Obviously this is a trivial example, imagine a much longer line command you want to copy/paste skipping an option on line 3 of many)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `HIST_REDUCE_BLANKS` option to prevent irrelevant whitespace from being added to the history list.

```
% ls \
bin
[output redacted]
% history
[...]
1005 ls \\nbin
% setopt HIST_REDUCE_BLANKS
ls \
bin
[...]
% history
[...]
1005 ls \\nbin
1006 history
1007 setopt HIST_REDUCE_BLANKS
1008 ls bin
```